# Getting Empty Result from Web Scrape Using XPath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests

I amusing the following code to scrape the ticket price from the "Cheapest" tab.  However I just get "`[]`" as a result.

Can someone verify my code and XPath are correct?  I have tried using both the relative ("//span[@class='title price']") and absolute XPath.  Also, I should note that I am using a service that renders the page first before using 'Request'.  The rendering should not be the problem.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.momondo.com/flight-search/PHL-VCE/2019-06-19-flexible/2019-06-25-flexible?sort=price_a')
sleep(5)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]')
print(price)
```

Comment: are you sure the page is loaded completely?

Comment: According to the service, the render is working.  Besides for potential issues with the render, does the code and XPath look correct to you?

Comment: I don't see the `Cheapest` node loading into tree as `page.content` not pulling the flights information. That's the reason why you are getting `[]` as output.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by according to the service? This page loads dynamically, the request that you are sending will only return a response with a 'skeleton' of the page, and the prices will be loaded dynamically( try using selenium or scrapy with splash). Once you get the page to load, you would have to scrape all the elements in the table.

Comment: Can you help me fix the code?  Do I just need to update the XPath? What should it be?

Comment: @supputuri Can you help me fix the code? Do I just need to update the XPath? What should it be?

Comment: It's not the issue with the xpath, primarly you are not getting the page.content which have the details you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The webpages data renders by java scripts so `request.get()` unable to returns the value you have expected.Use selenium `webdriver` and `BeautifulSoup` to retrieve the values.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re
 driver=webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://www.momondo.com/flight-search/PHL-VCE/2019-06-19-flexible/2019-06-25-flexible?sort=price_a&fs=flexdepart=~20190616;flexreturn=~20190622")
 soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
 allprice=[price.text.replace('\xa0',' ') for price in soup.find_all('div',class_=re.compile('_A _r _s _v'))]
    print(allprice)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
['1,280 USD', '1,185 USD', '1,156 USD', '1,205 USD', '1,278 USD', '1,747 USD', 'N/A', '1,461 USD', '1,374 USD', '1,311 USD', '1,509 USD', '1,516 USD', '1,561 USD', '3,310 USD', '1,256 USD', '1,077 USD', '1,146 USD', '1,186 USD', '1,202 USD', '1,397 USD', '1,391 USD', '1,342 USD', '1,167 USD', '1,113 USD', '1,157 USD', '1,149 USD', '1,488 USD', '1,355 USD', '1,235 USD', '1,055 USD', '1,136 USD', '1,114 USD', '1,190 USD', '1,376 USD', '1,258 USD', '1,422 USD', '1,301 USD', '1,117 USD', '1,114 USD', '1,154 USD', '1,212 USD', '1,596 USD', '1,422 USD', '1,429 USD', '1,231 USD', '1,114 USD', '1,164 USD', '1,186 USD', '1,271 USD']
```

Here you find beautiful soup doc [click here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)